# Для N десятичных цифр количество чисел, которые ими можно записать, равно 10 в степени N

Tags: математика, системы-счисления

Читал книгу `Выразительный Javascript` и наткнулся на определение которое не понял.

> Для N десятичных цифр количество чисел, которые ими можно записать, равно 10 в степени N.

Источник: [Выразительный Javascript - Числа](https://karmazzin.gitbooks.io/eloquentjavascript_ru/content/chapters/chapter1.html#%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0)

Comment: На запись числа N в k-ичной системе потребуется logk(N) цифр

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для одной десятичной цифры - это 10 чисел: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 - так?
Теперь рассмотрим две цифры. Для каждой из десяти первых цифр можно приписать рядом вторую - 10 вариантами, т.е. всего получается 10*10 = 100 = 10<sup>2</sup> разных чисел (00 01 02 ... 10 11 ... 97 98 99).

Рассуждая аналогично, получаем, что разных N-значных чисел - 10<sup>N</sup>.

Зачем так тяжеловесно объяснили такую тривиальную вещь - не знаю...

Comment: там это простое проходное предложение. Ни к чему там вот эти все рассмотрим, тем более, что утверждение действительно тривиальное.

Comment: @Harry, спасибо что помогли, но подскажите пожалуйста что они подразумевают под N, ибо если подставить число к примеру `0123456789` в контексте 10 в степени N, то уже не складывается картина.
`Для 0123456789 десятичных цифр количество чисел, которые ими можно записать, равно 10 в степени N. Аналогично, 64 битами можно выразить 2 в 64 степени чисел. Это довольно много.` Я понял что вы мне объяснили, но не пойму как это работает в контексте их примера.

Comment: О каком примере речь? По ссылке я посмотрел - никакого примера не увидел...

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, это плохой перевод. Имелось в виду, что используя разных десять цифр и допуская их повторения, в `N` позициях можно записать 10 в степени `N` разных чисел. Что является абсолютно очевидным.

Если цифр всего две, 0 и 1 - два возможных значения бита, то в 64-х битах (восьми байтах) можно записать 2 в 64-й степени разных значений.

Comment: а почему пишут: ` Для N десятичных цифр количество чисел, которые ими можно записать, равно 10 в степени N. Аналогично, 64 битами можно выразить 2 в 64 степени чисел. Это довольно много.
` По моему было бы аналогично, если бы они сравнивали 10³ и 2². Как записать тогда в десятичной системе счисления 64 бита?

Comment: Там говорится о восьмибайтовом типе данных и количестве различных значений, которое можно представить с помощью этого типа. При чем тут 10³ и 2²? "Как записать тогда в десятичной системе счисления 64 бита?" - смысл этой фразы от меня ускользает.

Comment: _Для N десятичных цифр количество чисел, которые ими можно записать, равно 10 в степени N._ Каким образом это предложение аналогично с _64 битами можно выразить 2 в 64 степени чисел_ ?

Comment: Когда цифр десять, а разрядов N, число вариантов - десять в степени N. Когда цифр две, а разрядов 64, число вариантов - два в степени 64. Я Вам уже написал, что перевод - плохой, косноязыкий.

Comment: ты не против пойти в чат и помочь мне понять, а то я ни черта не понимаю. Для меня здесь нет аналогии, разве что возведение в степень. почему там N, а там 64 бита.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69682/discussion-between-igor-and--).